# NSURLConnection error not working

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection

I am trying to detect if there is an error in my request using the if statement on `theConnection`. It enters the first part if successful fine but does not enter the else if there is an error. I am not sure why.

```
- (void)vehicleSearchRequest:(NSData *)postBodyData
{

    NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", serverAddress];

    //Set database address
    NSMutableString *databaseURL = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", address];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:databaseURL];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postBodyData length]];

    //SynchronousRequest to grab the data, also setting up the cachePolicy
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; //if request dose not finish happen within 60 second timeout.

    // Set up request
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/octet-stream" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postBodyData];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:180];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (theConnection) {
        // do animation thankyou here
        NSLog(@"Sucsess!");
        [self submitSuccessful];
    } else {
        // Inform the user that the connection failed from the connection:didFailWithError method
        NSLog(@"Connectin ERROR!!!");
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection error, Please try again" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];
    }

}
```

Comment: You won't get a `nil` `theConnection` object for **all** types of failures.  Some errors are apparent immediately, and others only show up after a while (for example, a timeout), in which case, you'll find out in the `didFailWithError:` callback.

Comment: cool I fixed it with your suggestion... oppsie.

Comment: What do you get when you NSLog(@"conn: %@", theConnection); right after the initialization?

Comment: You should download this [sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CacheInfo-MacOSX/Listings/Controller_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007751-Controller_m-DontLinkElementID_4) and run it.. put debug point or NSLog(@"%@", __FUNCTION__); on each method/function that begins with connection... and see what orders it is getting called.. what gets passed in when that function gets called etc.. its not the answer you were expecting but this is how you will learn.

Comment: Also its good to read this.. go over each method.. [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate)

Comment: Here is a working example.. [Link](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/how-to-make-http-request-from-iphone-and-parse-json-result/) seems pretty explanatory to me.

Comment: Show your error log @HurkNburkS.

Comment: Implement the delegate methods didFailWithError:

Comment: Where is the delegate methods of NSURLConnection ?? didFail, didReceive, didFinish etc???

Comment: I added them and its not working how it should.. :P

Answer (score 0):

Your code checks to see whether it was able to instantiate an `NSURLConnection` or not. This is a useful safety check, but will only fail in practice if you pass it a URL that the system does not support.

The connection itself is asynchronous, and so will take a little while to tell you if there was a problem or not. Implement its delegate methods to hear back from the server.